# Why is (process-file "git") slower than (process-file-shell-command "git") on Emacs for Windows

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

`(process-file "git")` is slower than `(process-file-shell-command "git")` on Emacs for Windows.

My environment:

- Windows 7
- GNU Emacs 24.2.1
- git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0

  ```
  (benchmark 10 '(process-file "git"))
  => "Elapsed time: 4.309000s"

  (benchmark 10 '(process-file-shell-command "git"))
  => "Elapsed time: 0.351000s"
  ```

I got same result with Cygwin git.

```
(benchmark 10 '(process-file "c:/cygwin/bin/git.exe"))
=> "Elapsed time: 5.583000s"

(benchmark 10 '(process-file-shell-command "c:/cygwin/bin/git.exe"))
=> "Elapsed time: 0.371000s"
```

Comment: Apparently that's a Windows-specific phenomenon.  At least, I can't reproduce it on OS X.  You may want to ask this on emacs-devel@gnu.org, though, since it's likely caused by some details of the Windows implementation, so it's best to ask the developers directly.

Comment: [ Wild guess. ]  Maybe one invocation works (and takes a little while to do its job) while the other signals an error and returns immediately?

Comment: process-file-shell-command will run process-file with very different args than a call to process-file directly. In fact when I do it, the program arg is changed to Emacs cmdproxy.exe with "git" as an arg, this could be a huge difference.

Comment: ;; standard call
    (benchmark 100 '(process-file "git")) 
    ;; what process-file-shell-command does
    (benchmark 100 '(process-file "C:/Users/jordon/Desktop/emacs-24.3/bin/cmdproxy.exe" nil nil nil "-c" "git"))

Comment: @Stefan that is what is happening. Running through cmdproxy.exe yields a "permission denied" error, while running git directly succeeds.

Comment: I don't see such error. How did you observe the error? What about if you invoke git in shell-mode which uses cmdproxy.exe?